# Can't reach element by using a combination of .parent() and .next() methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm binding the following function to a toggle button I have created to hide/unhide content that is located bellow the button, but on an other level in the DOM.

```
var togglelabel = packagehead.append("<div>").children().last().addClass("togglewrap").append("<label>")
        .children().last().addClass("toggle android header-toggle")
        .on('click', function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().next('.hidable').toggle();
        });
```

The html structure looks like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="packageheader">
        <span>Package #1501</span>
        <div class="togglewrap">
            <label class="toggle android header-toggle">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <p>
                    <span>More</span>
                    <span>Less</span>
                </p>
                <a class="slide-button">
                </a>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <p class="hidable">
        <pre>content here</pre>
    </p>
</div>
```

This code doesn't work to hide the `<p>` with the class `.hidable`.
I've tried 'debugging' the code using console.log() to see what element 'this' represents and found that it does, as expected, represent the label element.

So I thought that using the following chain:

```
$(this).parent().parent().next('.hidable').toggle();
```

Would correctly go 2 levels up to the `<div class="packageheader">` and then take the next sibling with the class hidable, which would be `<p class="hidable">`

Here is a screenshot of the structure, to be sure I didn't miss anything:
[image]

Comment: How did you define packagehead  ?

Comment: $(this).parents('.packageheader').siblings('.hidable').toggle();

Comment: @SVS No : this would toggle all .hidable at the same level, not just the one following the .packageheader (see answer made long before your comment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this :

```
$(this).closest('.packageheader').nextAll('.hidable').first().toggle();
```

Note that it's slightly preferable to use `closest` instead of `parent().parent()` as it won't break as easily when the HTML changes and it's easier for the maintainer to decipher what the code does.

Note also that your HTML is invalid, you can't have a `PRE` inside a `P`.

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/unafav/3/)

Comment: What's the point to select all .hidable to select a single one?

Comment: @Andy Do you have a better more readable solution not implying a heavy selector ? Then I would like to see it... And it doesn't select all, only the one that are after the .packageheader element.

Comment: I'm trying this code right now but it doesn't seem to hide the paragraph.

Comment: @Spyral The code I showed was only for the element selection. Add .toggle() to hide the paragraph (I edited to add it).

Comment: @dystroy I know, I tried it with the toggle but it still didn't hide the paragraph. I also posted a picture of the structure of the div. (I didn't downvote your post, or the other)

Comment: @Spyral I've added another precision (about the PRE) and a link to a demonstration.

Comment: @dystroy I didn't know that you can't put a pre inside a p.. Thank you for clarifying that! If I still want to use the pre because I'm using stringify to format JSON, and I need to use 'pre' to format it. What would you advise to use here as a solution? Just remove the p and make the pre .hidable?

Comment: @dystroy well yes you are right, I thought there is a way to find the only first next() element that hits the selector and stop searching at this point, aka querySelector behavior.

Comment: I just tried it with correct html, removing the pre, and it still doen't work

Comment: @Spyral Can you spot the differences between your code and the demonstration I made ?

Comment: @Andy I don't know of any clear and concise way of doing this with jQuery.

Comment: @dystroy yes, it's impossible with jQuery without custom-crafted code.

Comment: @dystroy yes the main difference is that you bind the .on('click') on the <a> element and I bind it on the <label> element. The reason I'm binding it on the label element is because I'm using a 'fancy toggle' button and I don't think it's even possible to click that <a> element on my toggle.

Comment: Don't bind on label elements : they yet have a predefined click handling logic (they're supposed to be linked to form elements).

Comment: @dystroy so what do you propose as a solution if I can't use the <a>

Comment: It's hard to tell for your exact case because it's strange not to be able to use the a element, but you should be able to replace the label with a span.

Comment: @dystroy it didn't work yet! The problem actually was that the click event apparantly triggered twice! once from the label and once from the input element! I also couldn't use "event.preventDefault()" to fix that problem cause that would stop the css animation of my toggle. I ended up with fixing it on a dirty way by adding a variable that can be 0 or 1 and checking if it's 1, then decrementing it and the other way around. So that the double triggering of the click event only fires the 'toggle()' once! I'll still accept your answer since it's a good/solid answer to my original question. thanks

Comment: It looks likes you should fix that double trigger. If that's because you have an event handler for two nested elements , of for an input and its label, or a similar case, you might want to use event.preventDefault (or return false in your jquery event handler).

Comment: @dystroy as I explained above I can't use those fixes, which are better, because that stops my css animation from being executed as well. Maybe I could bind it on the input instead of the label? even though I'm not sure I'm able to actually 'click' on the input cause I'm using the label as the clickable area I think. anyways, it's working now ^^